# Can we say frequency is equivalent to mass?

Tags: special-relativity, frequency, mass-energy

Is it possible to combine Einstein's $E = m{c}^{2}$ and Max Planck's $E = hv$ and conclude mass is equivalent to frequency? If no, where exactly is the problem in concluding the same?

Comment: Hint: what kind of particles does $E = h\nu$ hold for? What happens to "$E = mc^2$" then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula $E=h\nu$ is only applicable for photons. In the case of a photon you are right $\nu$ and mass proportional.

For particles other than photons we can use de Broglie wavelength which is given by
$$\lambda=\frac{h}{p}$$
For a particle with relativistic mass m and rest mass $m_0$(for photons $m_0=0$)-
$$E=mc^2=\gamma m_0c^2=\sqrt{(m_0c^2)^2+(pc)^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow  E=\sqrt{(m_0c^2)^2+(\frac{hc}{\lambda})^2}$$
In practice the above equation is not very useful.

Comment: How does your answer account for the experimental evidence that photon mass is zero?

Answer (score 0):

No. The mass of a photon is $0$. It has energy and momentum without having mass.